# PHP SOAP client not sending parameters when calling function

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I'm calling a service to authenticate, the service I'm calling is just "Authenticate" As displayed from __getFunctions:

```
[0]=> string(59) "AuthenticateResponse Authenticate(Authenticate $parameters)
```

I'm trying to call it like this:

```
$resp = $client->Authenticate(array('user'=>"user", 'password'=>"password"));
```

But then when I check lastrequest it seems as if I was not sending user name or password. So I get the result "Wrong user name or password":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.fsi.co.uk/services/evolution/04/09"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:Authenticate/></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I also tried formatting this request in different ways:

```
$resp = $client->Authenticate($params = array("Authenticate" => $autharr));
```

(Where Auth array is an associative array with user and password)

And even as a class:

```
class Authenticate{
    public $user = 'Rawr';
    public $password = 'Mew';
 }
$info = new Authenticate();
$resp = $client->Authenticate($info);
```

But all of them result in the same empty request, and hence in the same "wrong password" result. I believe this error has to do with the way I'm formatting the data, but I'm a bit stuck and everything I have tried from google has failed. So I would appreciate a hint or two here! Thanks!

(WDSL)

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:tns="http://www.fsi.co.uk/services/evolution/04/09" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" name="SecurityService" targetNamespace="http://www.fsi.co.uk/services/evolution/04/09">
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.fsi.co.uk/services/evolution/04/09">
<xsd:element name="Authenticate">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="loginName" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="password" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="AuthenticateResponse">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element xmlns:q1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Fsi.Platform.Contracts.Entities.ServiceModel" minOccurs="0" name="AuthenticateResult" nillable="true" type="q1:AuthenticationDto"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="AuthenticateDatabase">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="loginName" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="password" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="databaseName" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="AuthenticateDatabaseResponse">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element xmlns:q2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Fsi.Platform.Contracts.Entities.ServiceModel" minOccurs="0" name="AuthenticateDatabaseResult" nillable="true" type="q2:AuthenticationDto"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="LogOut">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="sessionId" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="LogOutResponse">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence/>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="AuthenticateOutlook">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="loginName" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="password" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="AuthenticateOutlookResponse">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element xmlns:q3="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Fsi.Platform.Contracts.Entities.ServiceModel" minOccurs="0" name="AuthenticateOutlookResult" nillable="true" type="q3:AuthenticationDto"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="AuthenticateDatabaseOutlook">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="loginName" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="password" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="databaseName" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="AuthenticateDatabaseOutlookResponse">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element xmlns:q4="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Fsi.Platform.Contracts.Entities.ServiceModel" minOccurs="0" name="AuthenticateDatabaseOutlookResult" nillable="true" type="q4:AuthenticationDto"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="AuthenticateDatabaseByAccountUserType">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="loginName" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="password" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="databaseName" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element xmlns:q5="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Fsi.Platform.Security.Contracts.Entities" minOccurs="0" name="accountUserType" type="q5:AccountUserTypeDto"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="AuthenticateDatabaseByAccountUserTypeResponse">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element xmlns:q6="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Fsi.Platform.Contracts.Entities.ServiceModel" minOccurs="0" name="AuthenticateDatabaseByAccountUserTypeResult" nillable="true" type="q6:AuthenticationDto"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="AuthenticateByAccountUserType">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="loginName" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="password" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element xmlns:q7="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Fsi.Platform.Security.Contracts.Entities" minOccurs="0" name="accountUserType" type="q7:AccountUserTypeDto"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="AuthenticateByAccountUserTypeResponse">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element xmlns:q8="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Fsi.Platform.Contracts.Entities.ServiceModel" minOccurs="0" name="AuthenticateByAccountUserTypeResult" nillable="true" type="q8:AuthenticationDto"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema xmlns:tns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Fsi.Platform.Contracts.Entities.ServiceModel" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Fsi.Platform.Contracts.Entities.ServiceModel">
<xsd:complexType name="AuthenticationDto">
<xsd:complexContent mixed="false">
<xsd:extension xmlns:q9="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Fsi.Platform.Contracts.ServiceModel" base="q9:BaseDto">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element xmlns:q10="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Fsi.Platform.Security.Contracts.Services" minOccurs="0" name="OperationResult" type="q10:AuthenticationResultCode"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="SessionId" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:extension>
</xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="AuthenticationDto" nillable="true" type="tns:AuthenticationDto"/>
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema xmlns:tns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Fsi.Platform.Security.Contracts.Services" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Fsi.Platform.Security.Contracts.Services">
<xsd:simpleType name="AuthenticationResultCode">
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:enumeration value="Unknown"/>
<xsd:enumeration value="Succeeded"/>
<xsd:enumeration value="NotAuthenticated">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:appinfo>
<EnumerationValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">4</EnumerationValue>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:enumeration>
<xsd:enumeration value="WrongUserNameOrPassword">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:appinfo>
<EnumerationValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">8</EnumerationValue>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:enumeration>
<xsd:enumeration value="GeneralFailure">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:appinfo>
<EnumerationValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">16</EnumerationValue>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:enumeration>
<xsd:enumeration value="LicensedAreaAccessDenied">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:appinfo>
<EnumerationValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">32</EnumerationValue>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:enumeration>
<xsd:enumeration value="ProductNotLicensed">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:appinfo>
<EnumerationValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">64</EnumerationValue>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:enumeration>
<xsd:enumeration value="BreachedLicenceEntities">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:appinfo>
<EnumerationValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">128</EnumerationValue>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:enumeration>
<xsd:enumeration value="DatabaseInvalidVersion">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:appinfo>
<EnumerationValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">256</EnumerationValue>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:enumeration>
<xsd:enumeration value="DatabaseNotAvailable">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:appinfo>
<EnumerationValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">512</EnumerationValue>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:enumeration>
<xsd:enumeration value="DatabaseAccessDenied">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:appinfo>
<EnumerationValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">1024</EnumerationValue>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:enumeration>
<xsd:enumeration value="FailedMaximumNumberUsersLoggedIn">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:appinfo>
<EnumerationValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">2048</EnumerationValue>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:enumeration>
<xsd:enumeration value="UserAlreadyLoggedIn">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:appinfo>
<EnumerationValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">4096</EnumerationValue>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:enumeration>
<xsd:enumeration value="SessionExpired">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:appinfo>
<EnumerationValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">8192</EnumerationValue>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:enumeration>
<xsd:enumeration value="AccountLockedOut">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:appinfo>
<EnumerationValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">12288</EnumerationValue>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:enumeration>
<xsd:enumeration value="PasswordExpired">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:appinfo>
<EnumerationValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">16384</EnumerationValue>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:enumeration>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:element name="AuthenticationResultCode" nillable="true" type="tns:AuthenticationResultCode"/>
</xsd:schema>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
<xs:element name="anyType" nillable="true" type="xs:anyType"/>
<xs:element name="anyURI" nillable="true" type="xs:anyURI"/>
<xs:element name="base64Binary" nillable="true" type="xs:base64Binary"/>
<xs:element name="boolean" nillable="true" type="xs:boolean"/>
<xs:element name="byte" nillable="true" type="xs:byte"/>
<xs:element name="dateTime" nillable="true" type="xs:dateTime"/>
<xs:element name="decimal" nillable="true" type="xs:decimal"/>
<xs:element name="double" nillable="true" type="xs:double"/>
<xs:element name="float" nillable="true" type="xs:float"/>
<xs:element name="int" nillable="true" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element name="long" nillable="true" type="xs:long"/>
<xs:element name="QName" nillable="true" type="xs:QName"/>
<xs:element name="short" nillable="true" type="xs:short"/>
<xs:element name="string" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="unsignedByte" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedByte"/>
<xs:element name="unsignedInt" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedInt"/>
<xs:element name="unsignedLong" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedLong"/>
<xs:element name="unsignedShort" nillable="true" type="xs:unsignedShort"/>
<xs:element name="char" nillable="true" type="tns:char"/>
<xs:simpleType name="char">
<xs:restriction base="xs:int"/>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:element name="duration" nillable="true" type="tns:duration"/>
<xs:simpleType name="duration">
<xs:restriction base="xs:duration">
<xs:pattern value="\-?P(\d*D)?(T(\d*H)?(\d*M)?(\d*(\.\d*)?S)?)?"/>
<xs:minInclusive value="-P10675199DT2H48M5.4775808S"/>
<xs:maxInclusive value="P10675199DT2H48M5.4775807S"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:element name="guid" nillable="true" type="tns:guid"/>
<xs:simpleType name="guid">
<xs:restriction base="xs:string">
<xs:pattern value="[\da-fA-F]{8}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{4}-[\da-fA-F]{12}"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
<xs:attribute name="FactoryType" type="xs:QName"/>
<xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:ID"/>
<xs:attribute name="Ref" type="xs:IDREF"/>
</xs:schema>
<xsd:schema xmlns:tns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Fsi.Platform.Contracts.ServiceModel" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Fsi.Platform.Contracts.ServiceModel">
<xsd:complexType name="BaseDto">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="PrimaryKeyId" type="xsd:long"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="PrimaryTableCatalogId" type="xsd:long"/>
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="ValidateOnly" type="xsd:boolean"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="BaseDto" nillable="true" type="tns:BaseDto"/>
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema xmlns:tns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Fsi.Platform.Security.Contracts.Entities" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Fsi.Platform.Security.Contracts.Entities">
<xsd:simpleType name="AccountUserTypeDto">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:appinfo>
<ActualType xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" Name="long" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
<xsd:enumeration value="Service">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:appinfo>
<EnumerationValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">2</EnumerationValue>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:enumeration>
<xsd:enumeration value="Import">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:appinfo>
<EnumerationValue xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">8</EnumerationValue>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:enumeration>
</xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:element name="AccountUserTypeDto" nillable="true" type="tns:AccountUserTypeDto"/>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="SecurityService_Authenticate_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Authenticate"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="SecurityService_Authenticate_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:AuthenticateResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="SecurityService_AuthenticateDatabase_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:AuthenticateDatabase"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="SecurityService_AuthenticateDatabase_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:AuthenticateDatabaseResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="SecurityService_LogOut_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:LogOut"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="SecurityService_LogOut_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:LogOutResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="SecurityService_AuthenticateOutlook_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:AuthenticateOutlook"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="SecurityService_AuthenticateOutlook_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:AuthenticateOutlookResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="SecurityService_AuthenticateDatabaseOutlook_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:AuthenticateDatabaseOutlook"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="SecurityService_AuthenticateDatabaseOutlook_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:AuthenticateDatabaseOutlookResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="SecurityService_AuthenticateDatabaseByAccountUserType_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:AuthenticateDatabaseByAccountUserType"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="SecurityService_AuthenticateDatabaseByAccountUserType_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:AuthenticateDatabaseByAccountUserTypeResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="SecurityService_AuthenticateByAccountUserType_InputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:AuthenticateByAccountUserType"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="SecurityService_AuthenticateByAccountUserType_OutputMessage">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:AuthenticateByAccountUserTypeResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="SecurityService">
<wsdl:operation name="Authenticate">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://www.fsi.co.uk/services/evolution/04/09/SecurityService/Authenticate" message="tns:SecurityService_Authenticate_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://www.fsi.co.uk/services/evolution/04/09/SecurityService/AuthenticateResponse" message="tns:SecurityService_Authenticate_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="AuthenticateDatabase">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://www.fsi.co.uk/services/evolution/04/09/SecurityService/AuthenticateDatabase" message="tns:SecurityService_AuthenticateDatabase_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://www.fsi.co.uk/services/evolution/04/09/SecurityService/AuthenticateDatabaseResponse" message="tns:SecurityService_AuthenticateDatabase_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="LogOut">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://www.fsi.co.uk/services/evolution/04/09/SecurityService/LogOut" message="tns:SecurityService_LogOut_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://www.fsi.co.uk/services/evolution/04/09/SecurityService/LogOutResponse" message="tns:SecurityService_LogOut_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="AuthenticateOutlook">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://www.fsi.co.uk/services/evolution/04/09/SecurityService/AuthenticateOutlook" message="tns:SecurityService_AuthenticateOutlook_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://www.fsi.co.uk/services/evolution/04/09/SecurityService/AuthenticateOutlookResponse" message="tns:SecurityService_AuthenticateOutlook_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="AuthenticateDatabaseOutlook">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://www.fsi.co.uk/services/evolution/04/09/SecurityService/AuthenticateDatabaseOutlook" message="tns:SecurityService_AuthenticateDatabaseOutlook_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://www.fsi.co.uk/services/evolution/04/09/SecurityService/AuthenticateDatabaseOutlookResponse" message="tns:SecurityService_AuthenticateDatabaseOutlook_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="AuthenticateDatabaseByAccountUserType">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://www.fsi.co.uk/services/evolution/04/09/SecurityService/AuthenticateDatabaseByAccountUserType" message="tns:SecurityService_AuthenticateDatabaseByAccountUserType_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://www.fsi.co.uk/services/evolution/04/09/SecurityService/AuthenticateDatabaseByAccountUserTypeResponse" message="tns:SecurityService_AuthenticateDatabaseByAccountUserType_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="AuthenticateByAccountUserType">
<wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://www.fsi.co.uk/services/evolution/04/09/SecurityService/AuthenticateByAccountUserType" message="tns:SecurityService_AuthenticateByAccountUserType_InputMessage"/>
<wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://www.fsi.co.uk/services/evolution/04/09/SecurityService/AuthenticateByAccountUserTypeResponse" message="tns:SecurityService_AuthenticateByAccountUserType_OutputMessage"/>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="SecurityService" type="tns:SecurityService">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="Authenticate">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://www.fsi.co.uk/services/evolution/04/09/SecurityService/Authenticate" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="AuthenticateDatabase">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://www.fsi.co.uk/services/evolution/04/09/SecurityService/AuthenticateDatabase" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="LogOut">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://www.fsi.co.uk/services/evolution/04/09/SecurityService/LogOut" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="AuthenticateOutlook">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://www.fsi.co.uk/services/evolution/04/09/SecurityService/AuthenticateOutlook" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="AuthenticateDatabaseOutlook">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://www.fsi.co.uk/services/evolution/04/09/SecurityService/AuthenticateDatabaseOutlook" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="AuthenticateDatabaseByAccountUserType">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://www.fsi.co.uk/services/evolution/04/09/SecurityService/AuthenticateDatabaseByAccountUserType" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="AuthenticateByAccountUserType">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://www.fsi.co.uk/services/evolution/04/09/SecurityService/AuthenticateByAccountUserType" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="SecurityService">
<wsdl:port name="SecurityService" binding="tns:SecurityService">
<soap:address location="http://app7-ipg.independent.local/Evolution_FIXD/Services/Basic/SecurityService.svc"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: If you provide the SOAP WSDL we might be able to help more.  Without it we're all just guessing at the format.

Comment: Oh I didnt even know you could request the WDSL from the service. Just googled how to do it and added it to the end of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, now that you've got the WSDL I see this in it:

```
<xsd:element name="Authenticate">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="loginName" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="password" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

So you could try this for your auth:

```
$resp = $client->Authenticate(array("loginName"=> $username, "password" => $password));
```

Of course you'll need to supply a valid `$username` and `$password` to that service, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not know you could get the specific names of the variables you need to parse as I didnt even know I could get the WDSL.
And I assumed I was doing something wrong because my request was not sending anything X) But apparently it was being sent, just not processed in any way by the service because of wrong naming.
Thanks!